# Mostrar resultado en textbox linq vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

Esta es mi consulta quieresa saber como pasar cada campo a los textbox

```css
 Dim query = From Q In Ejecutarconsulta("Select * from secreg where tabla='" _
                                         + tabla.Trim() + "' and codempresa='01'" ).AsEnumerable()
                                     Select New With {.tabla = Q.Field(Of String)("Tabla").Trim(),
                                                     .Secuencia = Q.Field(Of String)("Secuencia").Trim(),
                                                      .Letra = Q.Field(Of String)("Secuencia").Trim()}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando creas una linq este retorna una lista o coleccion de valores, si tienes varios items que mostrar lo normal seria que asignes el resultado a un control de lista como ser un ListView o DataGridView.

Ahora si quieres asignarlo a TextBoxs simples vas a tener que tomar un solo item

```
Dim query As String = String.Format("Select * from secreg where tabla='{0}' and codempresa='01'", tabla.Trim())
Dim data = Ejecutarconsulta(query).AsEnumerable()

Dim result = (From Q In data
             Select New With {.tabla = Q.Field(Of String)("Tabla").Trim(),
                             .Secuencia = Q.Field(Of String)("Secuencia").Trim(),
                              .Letra = Q.Field(Of String)("Secuencia").Trim()}).FirtOrDefault()


If result IsNot Nothing Then
    txtTabla.Text = result.tabla
    txtSecuencia.Text = result.Secuencia
    txtLetra.Text = result.Letra
End If
```

Como observaras es bueno separar un poco las lineas de codigo en varias operaciones, entonces al generar el linq uso el FirstOrDefault() para toma run solo dato que mostrar en los textbox

Comment: Muchas gracias Leandro con tu respuesta resolví mi problema